# Does this work for anyone?

Tags: java, graphics, runtime, japplet

This is the primary class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class demo_image extends JApplet {

private Image offscreen;
private double wildcat_x;
private int wildcat_y;
public void init() {

    player();
    wildcat_x = 50;
    wildcat_y = 50;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics gg =(Graphics2D)offscreen.getGraphics();
    Delay x = new Delay();
    gg.clearRect(0,0,getSize().width, getSize().height);
    gg.drawImage(offscreen,0,0,null);
    gg.drawString("Welcome to Java!!", 50, 60 );

    gg.drawImage(getImage(getDocumentBase(),"tyro.png"),(int)wildcat_x,wildcat_y, 250,300,this);
    wildcat_x+=2; 
    repaint();


    x.wait(30);

    gg.dispose();

}

public void player(){
    try{
        AudioClip b = getAudioClip( new URL(getCodeBase()+"track02.wav"));
        b.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

This is the secondary class

```
public class Delay
{
  public void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // ignoring exception at the moment
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is your problem / question? you can't just ask if it works, if it does for you it will for others

Comment: If it does work for 'anyone' it could only work for them if `"tyro.png"` etc. is in the right place on their computer, so I'm guessing ..'no'.  As an aside, I see you have included the `Delay` class, but not in the way I advised you to include it.  Please, if there is anything I suggest that you do not understand, ask me!  But be specific about what you do not understand.  I hate having to type 'a novel' every time someone misunderstands something.

Comment: I receive a huge run-time error every time I run the program (applet btw).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597788/graphics-program-long-stream-of-errors-using-jcreator-4-50?noredirect=1#comment30819102_20597788

Comment: The error is posted in that query.

Comment: `The error is posted in that query` So why are you creating another posting??? Keep the questions in a single posting so everybody knows what has been suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't override the paint() method. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent) and then you add the panel to the applet
2. Don't invoke repaint() from any painting method. This will cause an infinite loop.
3. Don't use sleeping code inside a painting method. If you want animation then use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
4. Don't read images from a painting method. The image should be read once when the class is created.
5. Class name start with an upper case character. "demo_image" should be "DemoImage".

Comment: As an aside.  These types of points come up so often that I wonder what it is that causes them.  Hangovers from another language?  Code from RoseIndia?  The way the human brain works? ..  Have you formed any theories on the matter?

Comment: Kind sir, if you could please show the modified class here, considering I am an utter noob, I'd be forever in your debt. Thanks though for the answer!

Comment: @Alphai: regarding, `"if you could please show the modified class here..."` -- please do not ask someone to modify your code or write code for you. We are happy to give suggestions, but you learn by writing your own code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I have often wondered the same. I am still mystified that similar problems keep arising. I know we have been giving advice similar to this for a decade. You would like to think that some of our answers would be found when people search the web. Actually I know many of our answers are found as I continually get up votes on old answers. I'm not sure were the beginners are finding their examples.